# Where is the default error log for upstart in Raspberrian?

Tags: boot, upstart

I created a file in `/etc/init/wiki.conf` to start up my wiki from a shell script on my Raspberry PI Model B:

```
# tw5nginx.conf

description "Nginx Tiddlywiki5 Wiki"
author "Me"

start on started networking
stop on shutdown

console log

script

  mkdir -p /home/pi/tw5/nginx
  cd /home/pi/tw5/nginx

  /home/runNginxWiki.sh
end script

respawn
```

I believe the script has failed to run, as my nginx proxy server doesn't see the wiki; but I don't know where the errors of the upstart script go.

Answer (score 2):

Found it in `/var/log/upstart`

All the log files are compressed; so if you want to view them you have to use `zcat`